# UDP/TCP server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm using IoT Core for recieve MQTT and HTTPs petitions

Now I want to use something similar to azure cloud services to listen all the time from a devices whose send me data through UDP/TCP

It would be possible to use a Lambda function? Maybe this will be too expensive because it could be called thousands of times per day.

If I use an EC2, how I could do it to receive and then send this data, for example, to S3/DynamoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda functions can't listen to UDP, or random TCP ports. You would only be able to use Lambda (in combination with API Gateway) to process HTTPS messages.

You are going to need to use EC2 or possibly one of the container services than run on EC2 like ECS or EKS.

Comment: So in this case, if I have to use EC2 (or maybe local pc), would I have to develop a program with the AWS SDK to receive the UDP data and transfer it to the other AWS service?

Comment: You would have to write a program that listens on the correct TCP/UDP ports using whatever programming language and libraries you like. Once that program receives a message it would use the AWS SDK for the programming language you are using to send that message to an AWS service like SQS/SNS/IoT, etc.

Answer (score 3):

For those seeing this after July 2019, Amazon released UDP support for their "Network Load Balancers".

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-udp-load-balancing-for-network-load-balancer/

By using this solution, you'd be able to have a network load balancer receive UDP packets from your field devices, then forward them on to one or more 'target groups' (likely EC2 instances or autoscaling groups in this case).

You'd still need to write the custom service which understands the format of UDP messages from your devices, and parses it into a message format that the AWS IoT core understands. That custom service would be running on whatever instances are in the target group which is receiving traffic from your network load balancer.

The main advantage here over exposing a single EC2 instance is that you're able to make changes to your UDP parsing / receiving code, boot up a new box with those changes, and migrate traffic to the new instance without an interruption of service. You also gain some redundancy (its possible to have the network load balancer split across multiple availability zones, and also have multiple target groups listen for the incoming UDP messages).